# Entity Framework removed all of my model classes from the solution, how do I get them back?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, edmx

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 with the Entity Framework and I have set of model classes that were generated by a set of tables in a database (SQL Server 2008 R2). Whenever I want to add tables, I usually click on the .edmx file and select "Update from Model" and it works just fine. I made some changes to the database schema and went to regenerate the models from the database and now all of my autogenerated classes in the .tt folder are gone! The database diagram in my .edmx file is fine, but how do I get all my classes back?